# Tokbox video chat give connection timeout error

Tags: html5-video, webrtc, opentok, videochat, tokbox

It working on same OS machine. If i am publisher with used of mac machine and subscriber side am using ubuntu os then give server connection timeout error.

Answer (score 0):

If OpenTok is working on the same machine but not across multiple machines, the issue is most likely caused by your network. You can check if your network supports webrtc using this tool: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/opentok-diagnostic/elanokbchpinmganpfaigciognfpcfei

If you are using flash, you have to enable rmtp ports. Check your network by going to the flash diagnostic tool here: http://tokbox.com/user-diagnostic/